# import psycopg2 : SystemError: initialization of _psycopg raised unreported exception\r on 2nd URL hit fails

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, mod-wsgi

I have two url to my application, which refers to same eg: localhost:8080 and abc.com. Pattern is that after restarting the apache server, only the first one URL works which I hit first and 2nd url does not work. Ideally both should work as both refers to same server.

I am getting below error for python 3.9. After following [this](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1144) I uninstalled and installed mod_wsgi 4.7.1 using python 3.9 pip and updated apache httpd.conf with output of `mod_wsgi-express.exe module-config`

```
[Mon May 24 04:31:30.115963 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8560:tid 104] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon May 24 04:31:32.121364 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9452:tid 904] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon May 24 04:31:32.303380 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8560:tid 104] AH00430: Parent: Child process 9452 exited successfully.
[Mon May 24 04:31:33.770657 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 612:tid 908] AH00455: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 24 04:31:33.771659 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 612:tid 908] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Mar 27 2021 11:42:37
[Mon May 24 04:31:33.771659 2021] [core:notice] [pid 612:tid 908] AH00094: Command line: 'F:\\Program Files\\NGDM\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d F:/Program Files/NGDM/Apache24'
[Mon May 24 04:31:33.781650 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 612:tid 908] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10632
[Mon May 24 04:31:34.815778 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10632:tid 872] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon May 24 04:32:18.161398 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] RUN_ID==>51683<==\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:18.163398 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] RUN_ID==>51683<==\r
C:\A\34\s\Modules\_decimal\libmpdec\context.c:57: warning: mpd_setminalloc: ignoring request to set MPD_MINALLOC a second time

[Mon May 24 04:32:29.651626 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202] mod_wsgi (pid=10632): Failed to exec Python script file 'F:/XYZ/test_wsgi.wsgi'.
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.651626 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202] mod_wsgi (pid=10632): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'F:/XYZ/test_wsgi.wsgi'.
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202]   File "F:/XYZ/test_wsgi.wsgi", line 6, in <module>\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202]     from app_e1 import app as application\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202]   File "f:/XYZ\\app_e1.py", line 6, in <module>\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202]     import psycopg2\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202]   File "c:\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2\\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202]     from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa\r
[Mon May 24 04:32:29.661629 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10632:tid 1440] [client 148.173.41.4:61202] SystemError: initialization of _psycopg raised unreported exception\r
```

Comment: I doubt may be the first url locks psycopg2 lib files and that is why it fails for 2nd url. Ref: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-General-Discussions/TestComplete-lock-library-files-after-first-run/td-p/188881 . But I don't know how to prove and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, restarting the server after adding below line in httpd.conf fixed the issue with multiple python sub interpreter. [Ref](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/application-issues.html).

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```